# uwp project name cannot begin with '<' character

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml

Out of nowhere my uwp project started to fail the build with this error :

[image: error]

I am pretty sure I made no changes to the project file and my git confirms that, I even tried pushing my code to tfs and CI-CD build on tfs is also failing now with the same error.

following is line 14 of my csproj file opened in notepad.

```
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17134.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a silly mistake by me, I did not close the Grid **>** closing bracket, because of which some compile time file in bin or obj folder was causing the issue, and xaml compiler did not ever care to tell me a syntax error in a xaml file.

Comment: Where file did you forgot to close the tag? in MainWindow.xaml?

Comment: No, it was a user control I was using and forgot to close the grid tag

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later.